# prevent a form from being submitted with SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, sweetalert

My goal is to only allow form submission after user clicks "Ok" on a SweetAlert box.

So, he clicks on an image (form), box appears with some instructions, he reads and clicks on "Ok", and then the form is submitted.

Here is the form code:

```
<form id="formpag" action="https://example.com/request.html" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="7055C88A445678A00461CFA120F4A2E7" />
<input type="image" src="https://example.com/buttons/subscriptions/120x53-subscribe.gif" name="submit" alt="Pay with Example.com - it is fast and reliable!" />
</form>
```

Now the jQuery/Sweet Alert part:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

 $(function() {
   $('#formpag').submit(function() {

   swal({   title: "Be Advised",
            text: "You need to check your email account after payment.",
            imageUrl: "images/thumbs-up.jpg" });        
          });
      });
   });
```

Problem: as it is now, box is showing to user, but after a few seconds, the form is being submitted, even without him clicking the OK button on the SweetAlert box.

Form must only be submitted if he clicks "OK".

Any help would be much appreciated. (sorry, I know it is a silly question, but SweetAlert documentation did not help me).

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default handling. Update your function to following

```
 $('#formpag').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    swal({   title: "Be Advised",
            text: "You need to check your email account after payment.",
            imageUrl: "images/thumbs-up.jpg" });        
     });
 });
```

For reference - http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: not quiet there. Form is not being submited after clicking "ok".

Comment: @LuisRock - You need to bind the event to "ok" button

Comment: ok. how do I do it? There is no "ok" button on sweetalert's code.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it. I found another SweetAlert code, more suitable to my need, and I could mix it to a jquery basic function.

Here is the final result:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {

$(function() {
  $('#formpag').submit(function() {
    event.preventDefault();

  swal({
    title: "Be advised",
    text: "You need to check your email account after payment.",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: false,
    confirmButtonColor: 'blue',
    confirmButtonText: 'Ok, got it.',
    closeOnConfirm: false,

  },
  function(){
     $('#formpag').submit();
   });  
  });
 });
});
```